# This 5X binding buffers where experiment participates in?

Tags: experiment

I saw 5X bingind buffer maded by;

- 100mM HEPES, pH 7.6
- 5mM EDTA
- 50mM ammonium sulfate
- 5mM DTT
- 1% Tween-20
- 150mM potassium chloride

which reaction helps this buffer? I don't consider to this buffer participates in which experiment by name. Although this buffer have another name but they writes just '5X bonding buffer'..

Comment: From what kind of reaction/protocol did you take this description?

Comment: I saw that recipie at pre-made buffer selling site. there's no mentioned about buffer usage.

Comment: Can you give us the link?

Comment: http://www.biosesang.com/bbs/shop/item.php?it_id=B2003 <<here. Application used by 'Applications: Suitable for molecular biology applications.'.

Comment: The description says "binding buffer" without specifying. This is pretty standard stuff, containing a buffer (Hepes), some salt and detergents. Nothing too special, but I wouldn't use a "one fits all" buffer.